# Sending Form Data to the Sever using AngularJS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, httpresponse

I want to send  form Data from my HTML/AngluarJS page by POST to the server (NodeJS), When submit I'm getting 400 (Bad request)

HTML Page that uses ng-submit:

```
<div class="container start"  ng-controller="adminController">
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-body"><h1>Administration</h1>
  <!-- form -->
   <form class="form-signin" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="adminController">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Add new Bird</h2>
    <select name= "tagType" id= "inputTag" class="form-control" placeholder="Tag Type" ng-modal="bird.tagType">
      <option ng-repeat="tag in tags" value="{{option.id}}">{{tag.tagName}}</option>
    </select><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTag()">Add Tag</button>
    <br/><br/>
     <select name = "specie" id= "inputSpecie" class="form-control" placeholder="Specie Category" ng-modal="bird.specie">
      <option ng-repeat="specie in species" value="{{option.id}}">{{specie.latinName}}</option>
    </select>
    <br/> 
     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addSpecie()">Add Specie</button>
        <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="inputSex" class="form-control" placeholder="Sex"  ng-modal="bird.sex"/>
        <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="inputRFID" class="form-control" placeholder="RFID Value" ng-modal="bird.rfid"/>
        <br/><br/> 
    <textarea id="inputComment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-modal="bird.comment"></textarea>
        <br/><br/> 
    <input type="file" ng-model="form.file_avatar" id="file_avatar"  />
        <br/><br/>  

    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

  </div> 
</div>
```

My Controller Script

```
angular.module('test').controller('adminController', function($scope, $http)
 {
    $http.get('/api/adminPanel').then(function (response) {
        // create a blank object to handle form data.
        $scope.bird = {};
        $scope.species = response.data.species;
        $scope.tags = response.data.tags;
        $scope.submit = function() 
        { 

        console.log(" Get fields values and Insert in the DB !");
        // posting Data to server
        $http.post('/api/adminPanel/create',  {'bird': $scope.bird}).then(function (response) {
        // sucess post 
         });
        // failure post

        }

         });

    });
```

Database script (adminPanel.js)

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
      var specie = req.body.specie;
      var comment = req.body.comment; 
      var sex = req.body.sex; 

       // var birdSpecie = req.body.specie;
       // console.log(" the Bird specie is " + birdSpecie); 
       console.log('the post request: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
       database.addAnimal(specie,sex,comment).then(function()
        {
        res.sendStatus(200);}
        ,next);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

your controller should be something like

```
angular.module('test').controller('adminController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.bird = {};
    $scope.submit = function() { 
      $http.post('/api/adminPanel/create',  $scope.bird).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);// as you need
      });
    };

  });
```

and your server side should be:

```
router.post('/api/adminPanel/create', function(req, res, next) {
      var specie = req.body.specie;
      var comment = req.body.comment; 
      var sex = req.body.sex;

      // your rest of code
      return res.status(200).send("success") // return 200 and success message
});
```

Comment: @shaihab  the code now is blocked in POST api/adminPanel/create (400)

Comment: if your router like:` var router = express.Router();` then use `router.route('/path').post(function(req, res){..})`

Comment: @shaihab ,Okay thanks a lot, I'm printing the req.body on the server script console.log('the post request: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));  , the req.body is empty

Comment: no need to use `JSON.stringify` just use `req.body`

Comment: without JSON.stringify I'm getting : "the post request : [object object]" , why there is no data in the req body, maybe I'm missing something in controller ?